# When I create a series of spectrograms from a long audio file, the colour intesities vary noticably

Tags: python, numpy, librosa, spectrogram

I'm using python, librosa, np.  The audio is stereo, 44.1k, about 2gb, 3hrs
First I convert the audio to mon, then in 60 second chunks I calculate the maximum power.
Next I use then highest max power as the global max power reference to generate the spectrograms.
I use the same f_high, and f_low
same db_high and db_low
same n_fft, hope langth and n_mels.
Same sample rate, and same max power reference.

basically this to get global max power ref

```
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(y), samples_per_chunk)):
    y_chunk = y[i : i + samples_per_chunk]
    S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(
        y=y_chunk,
        sr=sr,
        n_fft=n_fft,
        hop_length=hop_length,
        n_mels=n_mels,
        fmin=f_low,
        fmax=f_high,
    )
    maxpower = np.max(S)
    if maxpower > global_max_power:
        global_max_power = maxpower
```

then I use that max power to create the images
convert to db
S_dB = librosa.power_to_db(
S,
ref=max_power,
amin=10 ** (db_low / 10.0),
top_db=db_high - db_low,
)

render image

```
    plt.figure(figsize=(image_width / 100, video.get("height", 100) / 100))
    librosa.display.specshow(
        S_dB,
        sr=sr,
        cmap=audiovis.get("cmap", "magma"),
        hop_length=hop_length,
        fmin=f_low,
        fmax=f_high,
    )
```

if I make the image very wide, so no chunking is required (using a smaller file), I do not see the color intensity variation in the audio.
when I process the audio in chunks, it appears, yet the parameters controlling the process are the same.

I'm not sure how to diagnose further.

Comment: How is the variable `max_power` defined? Is it defined in the same way as `maxpower` ?

Comment: I save maxpower from the profiling stage, and retrieve it later in the image generation stage.  I have printed it our at various stages, it's the same throughout.

I think it might be related to the fact that during profiling I use quite small chunks
In librosa.feature.melspectrogram, and for image generation stage I use much large amounts of audio.   I'm not sure if that has an effect, but it is a difference.

Comment: also, I generated a 15 min test file with pink noise, and tried profiling chunk of both 300 secs and 60sec.  both produced very similar maxpower values.  which when applied to all the spectrograms, I can see the color differences, albeit less, which is interesting.